# basic 2d gaming question involving arrays and json javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

[image: 2d javascript question]

Now that the format of this game is established let's start writing some functionality one small piece at a time. For this part, write a function named "movePlayer" that takes as parameters a JSON string representing a level in the format above and a string representing the first movement of the player. The movement string will be either "w", "a", "s", or "d" based on the direction the player intends to move with "w" for up, "a" for left, "s" for down, and "d" for right. Return the new player location as an array in the format [x, y]. Remember to check for walls, locked doors, and the exit as the player cannot move through these (you can assume the player has no keys and does not have all the crystals). You may assume that the player did not walk into a lava tile. If the player walked into the edge of the map it should be treated as a wall (Ex. walking to the right while already on the right edge of the map shouldn't move the player)

```
function movePlayer(json_object, f){
    var level = JSON.parse(json_object);
    var grid = level["grid"];
    var pos = level["start"];
    var x = pos[0];
    var y = pos[1];

    if (f=="w"){
        y = y - 1;
    }
    else if (f=="s"){
        y = y + 1;
    }
    else if (f=="a"){
        x = x - 1;
    }
    else if(f=="d"){
        x = x + 1;
    }


    if (grid[y][x] == 1 || grid[y][x] == 3 || grid[y][x] == 7){
        pos = level["start"];
    }


    else if (grid.includes(grid[y][x])){
        pos = [x, y];
    }
    else{
        pos = level["start"]
    }
    return pos;
}
```

function movePlayer incorrect on input ['{"start": [2, 1], "grid": [[1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 3, 0, 7], [1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0]]}', 'w']

returned: [2, 1]
expected: [2, 0]

I'm so confused and don't know how to fix this, if anyone could help I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get [2,0], but then fall into checks and last `else` statement returns you to [2,1], which is your `start`.

I think you are mistaken in `grid.includes(grid[y][x])` condition, it is always false, because `grid` is array of arrays and you are checking it for exact integer value.

Comment: Any idea how I'd go about fixing that? If I remember correct to make it into array of arrays I'd do double brackets around x and y, but I just tried that and it's still giving the same answer.

Comment: But what did you want to check there? I dont understand the logic base of this checking

Comment: Not quite sure haha been stuck on this question for a couple of hours, I just picked up Javascript, well coding in general 2 months ago.

Comment: If you don't understand what your code is doing, I guess, debugging it will become a long journey for you.

Comment: I know what the code is doing that i wrote, I just didn't know what you meant on your answer part.

Comment: I asked what does 'grid.includes(grid[y][x])' mean? What it is checking for? This looks like a mistake but I cant tell if it is or not until I understand the reason for this check.

Comment: checks to see if the grid position the player moved to is in the given grid.

Comment: Ahh ohh.. Totally incorrect. Use y >= 0 && y < grid.length && x >= 0 && x < grid[y].length)